# Use LESS class from another file [Symfony2]

Tags: php, css, symfony, less

I'm working on Symfony2 and i use Less for my stylesheets.
I've an error when i'm trying to use a class from another file :

In my main.less file :

```
.noBorderNoOutline  { border : none !important; outline : none !important; }
```

And in my forms.less file, i do :

```
@import 'main.less';
input, select {
    .noBorderNoOutline();
    width           : 250px;
    height          : 50px !important;        
    box-shadow      : 0 0 2px #555 !important;
    border          : 1px #aaa solid !important;
    padding-left    : 10px;
    margin-bottom   : 10px;
}
```

I use lessphp to compile less files and yui compressor, my configuration is :

```
    filters:
    yui_css:
        jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar"
    yui_js:
        jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar"
    cssrewrite: ~
    lessphp:
        apply_to: "\.less$"
        formatter: "lessjs"
        preserve_comments: true
        presets:
            my_variable: "#000"
```

The files are in the same bundle and same folder.

In my TWIG template I do :

```
{% stylesheets filter='yui_css'
      '@MyBundle/Resources/public/css/forms.less'
%}
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url}}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

I've an error : **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)** 
The class 'noBorderNoOutline' is undefined.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use the mixin as a function if it has no arguments. However you do need to define it like a function in your main.less file.

Define it like this:

```
.noBorderNoOutline()  { border : none !important; outline : none !important; }
```

Use it like this:

```
input, select {
    .noBorderNoOutline;
    width           : 250px;
    height          : 50px !important;        
    box-shadow      : 0 0 2px #555 !important;
    border          : 1px #aaa solid !important;
    padding-left    : 10px;
    margin-bottom   : 10px;
}
```

Hope this solves your issue :) Good luck!

Comment: Sorry but i've the same error : NameError: .noBorderNoOutline is undefined

Comment: Can you try to debug whether it is the compiler script or the actual less files? Try using winless or another less compiler to compile the less files and include the result manually in the project. See what errors it throws.

Comment: I try to compile file in command line : lessc directory/* > style.css
And it works i've no error but same problem on Symfony.

I don't know for your answer ...

Comment: It's probably an issue with the steps the compiler is taking then, you can try to rearrange the files into an all.less file that @imports the main.less first then the form.less . You should then remove the import main.less from the form.less. Then include the resulting all.css in your site.

Comment: Yes it works with a main file !
Thanks for your help !

Comment: No worries :) Don't forget to close the answer!